# Will factory reset affect dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, reset

I want to factory reset Ubuntu on a dual booted 2012-is iMac. Will factory reset function leave the Mac side and dual boot intact?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for [https://apple.stackexchange.com/](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) than AskUbuntu.  It has nothing to do with Ubuntu and more to do with what an iMac factory reset would do.

Comment: This is a question for the Apple site.  However, 'factory reset' usually means what it means - reset everything back to factory state, including all partitions.  I would not trust a factory reset to do what you expect it would and leave your dual boot alone

Comment: It's unclear what you really have in mind when you write "*factory reset Ubuntu on a dual booted ... iMac*". Ubuntu does not have a "factory reset" feature. But iMacs do. Are you wondering happens if you factory-reset your iMac? (It will erase Ubuntu and all your data and restore MacOS)  Or are you envisioning something else?